# @mediaquery ignora propiedad padding

Tags: css3, mediaqueries

@mediaquery esta trabajando bien con todas las propiedades excepto con el padding, al que ignora.. ¿por que pasa esto y cono puedo solucionarlo? ¿se trata de un bug o que?..pongo mi sintaxis por si esta mal codificada y no me he dado cuenta (ayuda por favor!):

```
@media ( max-width : 500px ) {
  header div {
  padding : 0;
  text-align : center;
  border: 1px solid red;
  }
}
```

Tambien he probado con esto (pero tampoco funciona) :

```
@media only screen and ( max-width : 500px ) {
  header div {
    padding : 0;
    text-align : center;
    border: 1px solid red;
 }
}
```

Comment: ¿Puede ser que tengas otro estilo que esté pisando a este?

Comment: intenta agregando esto: padding : 0 !important;

Comment: Si pero ¿de eso se trata mediaquery no? de pisar los estilos cada vez que se detecte una nueva resolucion.... ese estilo (que piensas que puede estar interfiriendo) esta por debajo....es decir mi mediaquerie esta encima de todos los estilos principales, y funciona sobreescribiendo todas las otras propiedades excepto el padding

Comment: Si tienes una propiedad css con !important no la sobreescribe

Comment: Bryro+ Funcionó, gracias...ahora si puedes por favor explícame por que las otras propiedades funcionan sin el "important" y por que el paddin no. ¿es un bug o que?

Comment: Y que alguien me explique tambien cual de las dos sintaxis que he mostrado es la correcta, grcias

Comment: ¿Dices que las mediaqueries estan por encima del resto de estilos? Si quieres que sobreescriban a otros estilos debería estar debajo, el css se lee de arriba hacia abajo, las reglas de mas abajo sobreescriben a las de más arriba

Comment: ahh.. creo que me estoy acostumbrado mucho a java scipt, por eso se me ha quedado que es buena práctica poner todas las variables arriba :v...voy a mover las queries hacia abajo a ver si se soluciona sin poner la palabra IMPORTANT

Comment: Cuando se usa important en un estilos CSS, gana a todas las etiquetas que usted tenga, Important esta encima de id class, rol y las demas. Por eso cuando usas important si hay otra propiedad que afecte la misma important gana a a esa y añade las nuevas propiedades e ignora las demas.